# Save product "custom fields" values using woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, custom-fields

I was trying to set WooCommerce product price dynamically using user inputted values in custom fields in product page.

Everything works fine except, **I cannot show the custom fields data into admin order details & emails.**

I don't have any idea how to get debug results, as it doesn't return anything in Ajax responses. Either the checkout page completes and reloads to 'completed order' page, or I get error 500.

Here is the code where I'm stuck:

```php
// Get cart item custom data and update order item meta and display in orders and emails
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 2 );

function save_order_item_custom_meta_data( $item, $values ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    $owner = $values['custom_data']['share_owner'] ?? '';
    $getAmount = $values['custom_data']['dynamic_amount'] ?? '';

    // $pmType = '';
    // $pmAmount = '';
    
    // if($owner && $getAmount){
    //     $pmType = __('Payment Breakdown', $domain );
    //     $pmAmount = '30&euro; + ( '. number_format((int) $getAmount) .' &times; 0.05&euro; )';
    // }else{
    //     $pmType = __('Donation Amount', $domain );
    //     $pmAmount = number_format((int) $getAmount) . '&euro;';
    // }

    $item->update_meta_data( $owner, $getAmount ); //returns empty string

}
```

The rest of my related code *(for testing the custom price)*:

```php
// Display custom input fields in single product page
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'add_product_custom_fields', 20 );
function add_product_custom_fields(){
    $domain =  'woocommerce';
    printf( '<div id="owner"><div class="lined-up"><input type="radio" id="yes" name="share_owner" value="1"><label for="yes">%s</label></div><div class="lined-up"><input type="radio" id="no" name="share_owner" value="0"><label for="no">%s</label></div></div>', __( 'I own share', $domain ), __( 'I do not own share', $domain ), );

    $value = isset( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] ) ? sanitize_key( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] ) : '';
    printf( '<div id="dyn_amount" style="display:none;"><label for="dynamic_amount">%s</label><input name="dynamic_amount" id="dynamic_amount" value="%s" min="30" type="number"/></div>', __( 'Amount', $domain ), esc_attr( $value ) );
}

// Add custom fields data to cart items and make price calculation
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'custom_add_cart_item_data', 20, 2 ); 
function custom_add_cart_item_data( $cart_item, $product_id ){

    if( isset( $_POST['share_owner'] ) ){
        $cart_item['custom_data']['share_owner'] = (int) sanitize_key( $_POST['share_owner'] );
    }

    if( isset( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] ) ){
        $cart_item['custom_data']['dynamic_amount'] = sanitize_key( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] );
    }

    // Make calculation and save calculated  price
    if( isset( $_POST['share_owner'] ) && isset( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] ) ){
        $own_share      = (int) sanitize_key( $_POST['share_owner'] );
        $dynamic_amount = (int) sanitize_key( $_POST['dynamic_amount'] );

        //If selected share owner we need to calculate price according to input value
        if( $own_share ){
            // calculating the amount (share amount * 0.05) + 30
            $total_price = ( ( $dynamic_amount * 0.05 ) + 30.0 );
            $cart_item['custom_data']['price'] = round($total_price, 2);
        } else{
            //Otherwise its a donation, no calculation needed
            $total_price = $dynamic_amount;
            $cart_item['custom_data']['price'] = round($total_price, 2);
        }
    }

    return $cart_item;
}

// Display custom data in cart and checkout pages
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_item_data', 'udaac_display_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 2 );
function udaac_display_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_data, $cart_item ) {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    $input_amount = $cart_item['custom_data']['dynamic_amount'] ?? '';

    if ( isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['share_owner'] ) ){
        $owner = (int) $cart_item['custom_data']['share_owner'];
        $paymentType = '';
        $paymentOrShareAmount = '';

        if($owner){
            $paymentType = __('Payment Breakdown', $domain );
            $paymentOrShareAmount = '30&euro; + ( '. number_format((int) $input_amount) .' &times; 0.05&euro; )';
        }else{
            $paymentType = __('Donation Amount', $domain );
            $paymentOrShareAmount = number_format((int) $input_amount) . '&euro;';
        }

        $cart_data[] = array(
            'name' => $paymentType,
            'value' => $paymentOrShareAmount
        );
    }

    return $cart_data;
}

// Set the new calculated price replacing cart item price
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'udaac_set_cart_item_calculated_price', 20, 1 );
function udaac_set_cart_item_calculated_price( $cart ) {
    if ( is_admin() && ! defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) )
        return;

    if ( did_action( 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' ) >= 2 )
        return;

    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
        if( ! isset( $cart_item['custom_data']['price'] ) ){
            continue;
        }
        if( $cart_item['custom_data']['price'] > 0 ){
            // Set the calculated item price (if there is one)
            $cart_item['data']->set_price( (float) $cart_item['custom_data']['price'] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [UPDATE] [Solved]

I was able to solve the issue. To debug, I've enabled wp_debug_log. The log was showing a random string like "tufyg638788fdw34" for `var_dump($values);`

Then I tried passing all the parameter for `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook into the function.

`add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_custom_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {error_log(print_r($values, true));}`
It solved the issue & debug.log file have shown the right values.

Comment: I have answered… please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

There are some mistakes in your code.

Try the following instead (untested), that will save the necessary data as custom order item metadata with the correct `meta_keys` to be used, and will replace the displayed meta keys, with readable label strings:

```php
// Utility function: Convert label string to a correct meta key 
function sanitize_meta_key( $label ) {
    return str_replace('-','_',sanitize_title($label));
}

// Save custom cart item data as order item meta and display this meta data 
// on orders line item(s) in admin order pages, emails and customer orders. 
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_order_item_custom_meta_data', 10, 4 );
function save_order_item_custom_meta_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order ) {
    if ( isset($values['custom_data']['share_owner']) && isset($values['custom_data']['dynamic_amount']) ) {
        $domain         = 'woocommerce';
        $custom_data    = $values['custom_data'];
        $share_owner    = $custom_data['share_owner'];
        $dynamic_amount = (int) $custom_data['dynamic_amount'];

        if( $share_owner ){
            $label      = __('Payment Breakdown', $domain );
            $meta_value = '30&euro; + ( '. number_format($dynamic_amount) .' &times; 0.05&euro; )';
        } else {
            $label      = __('Donation Amount', $domain );
            $meta_value = number_format((int) $dynamic_amount) . '&euro;';
        }

        $item->update_meta_data( sanitize_meta_key($label), $meta_value ); 
    }
}

// Add readable "meta key" label name replacement
add_filter('woocommerce_order_item_display_meta_key', 'filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key', 10, 3 );
function filter_wc_order_item_display_meta_key( $display_key, $meta, $item ) {
    if( $item->get_type() === 'line_item' ) {
        $domain = 'woocommerce';
        $label1 = __('Payment Breakdown', $domain );
        $label2 = __('Donation Amount', $domain );

        if( $meta->key === sanitize_meta_key( $label1 ) ) {
            $display_key = $label1;
        } elseif( $meta->key === sanitize_meta_key( $label2 ) ) {
            $display_key = $label2 ;
        }
    } 
    return $display_key;
}
```

It should better work now. You may have to make some changes in my code, as I have tried to guess what you were trying to do.

Note: You should also add `checked` attribute to the first input radio button, to make it checked by default.